# ng-init assign values conditionally

Tags: angularjs

I found an unexpected behavior of `ng-init`. According to the doc `The ngInit directive allows you to evaluate an expression in the current scope.` So I'm trying to assign a value in a variable conditionally. Here is my code

```
<a ng-href="#" ng-click="flag = !flag;" ng-init="data = (flag == true) ? 'Value For Success' : 'Value for false'; "> {{data}}</a>
```

If in expression I pass `false` then false value will be assigned to variable and if I pass `true`, then true value will be assigned. I can achieve it by calling a function but I thought if I could assign value in a single line then why I need to write a function for that. Please suggest what I'm missing ?

Check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqbjuwzc/)

Answer (score 6):

why [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) ?

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

*see the documentation.*

in your case,

if you use  `ng-init="data = (flag == true) ? 'Value For Success' : 'Value for false'; "` angular will create a scope variable called `data` and initialize it to `'Value For Success'` or `'Value for false'` based on condition. And `ng-init` execute one time only so there is no way to change the `data` scope variable.

Comment: Okay.. Got your point. This line is meaningful `ng-init execute one time only so there is no way to change the data scope variable` :-)

Comment: Is there any reason why I can't use ng-if somewhere on the page to initialize the select default value?  In testing it seems to work....

<div ng-if="data.length==1 ? selectedValue = data[0] : undefined;"></div>

In my case the init is setting a select/option default when the array only has one choice to select.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use ng-case or ng-if, wich can assign value to your {{ data }} based on your following conditions.

Comment: Are you sure that `ng-case` exists ? BTW, `ng-if` does not work like as you said. :(

Comment: Y, sorry, ng-if is used to display elements. My bad ^^

Comment: Second mistake : it's ng-switch (the switch case make me think bad!)

Answer (score -3):

```
ng-bind="{1:'Text One', 2:'Text Two',3:'Text Three'}[variable]"
```

variable, In this case it is numerical, according to the value it contains, it will load the text ...

Comment: Please provide your answer in English. Thank you.

Comment: ng-bind is for displaying the values not for init