# Initialize ng model in angular material input

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to initialize ng-model with the custom using ng-init. But its not displaying the value in html page.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
   <input disabled="" ng-model="ctrl.userDetail.AccountLockStatus" ng-init="ctrl.userDetail.AccountLockStatus = (ctrl.userDetail.AccountStatus === 'Y')?'Locked':'Not Locked'">
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: Working fine for me, http://jsfiddle.net/2f6qscrp/220/. If you open your browser console, are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Fissio I am using angular 1.5 so we I am not using .controller. I am using it as component and then rendering HTML like this -

 var app = angular.module('home');
  
app.component('userProfile', {
  template: require('./user-profile.component.html'),
  controllerAs: 'ctrl',
  controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', controller]
 });
  
   function controller($scope, $rootScope) {
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `md-switch` or `md-checkbox` for this. They provide `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` settings.

```
<md-switch ng-model="ctrl.userDetail.AccountStatus" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'">
  Account Lock Status
</md-switch>
```

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSwitch

Comment: This is from the examples, if it is not working you should provide some example codepen or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way in `controller`:

```
$scope.init = function() {
  if($scope.userDetail.AccountLockStatus === 'Y') {
     $scope.userDetail.AccountLockStatus = 'Locked'
  }else {
     $scope.userDetail.AccountLockStatus = 'Not Locked'
  }
}

$scope.init();
```

In template:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
   <input disabled="" ng-model="ctrl.userDetail.AccountLockStatus">
</md-input-container>
```

Don't make conditional `ng-init`, see this link: [ng-init assign values conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243731/ng-init-assign-values-conditionally)