# AngularJS Setting SELECT default

Tags: angularjs

I have read several postings about using ng-init with a conditional statement is not a good idea but I'm wondering if the problem of the data going out of scope or any other issues exist if I was to use an ng-if as follows:

```
<div ng-if="data.length==1 ? selectedValue=data[0] : undefined;"></div>

<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="obj as obj.displayValue for obj in data"></select>
```

This seems to work.

[Reference to invalid use of ng-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243731/ng-init-assign-values-conditionally)

Comment: Conditionals can be used in `ng-if` but not really clear what you are trying to accomplish. It's very rare that you even need to use `ng-init` if used properly...most people should just forget that it even exists

Comment: You're trying to bypass the rule "don't use ng-init" by reimplementing it using ng-if, making it even worse (the expression will be reevaluated at each change detection). You're missing the point. This code should be in the controller, not the view.

Comment: Yea, I understand the concept of controller vs. view but in this case the same controller init routine is used for a lot of reports and I was trying to short cut creating but yet another sub routine.